# How connect to db when running Dockerfile?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, intellij-idea, docker-desktop

I have a spring boot app that connects fine to my PostgreSQL server running locally in Desktop Docker.

Than I wrote a simple Dockerfile to run my app in container. Container starts but can't connect to my db server with error message:

Connection to localhost:5432 refused.

Why and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access localhost from inside a docker container you can use the IP of your computer. Localhost or 127.0.0.0 donsen't work.

Answer (score 1):

Use docker compose to connect the two docker containers.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/

On this page you can see an example on how to connect to containers using docker compose:

https://dev.to/mozartted/docker-networking--how-to-connect-multiple-containers-7fl

Answer (score 1):

If they are on seperate Docker networks, use:

`docker.host.internal`

This connects to the Docker host machine. So if your PostgreSQL instance is exposed on 5432, `docker.host.internal` will route to that instance through the host from other containers.

Alternatively, set them up in the same network using docker compose or by creating a network and attaching both containers to them. They can then communicate with container name.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/